# subtract hours as string in Calendar Instance in java

Tags: java, calendar

I have the hours format in string as 24hours format..."YYYYmmddHHmmss"(year,month,date,hours,mins,seconds)
suppose if i pass the hours as 2hours means,it should subtract 2 hours from the currentDateTime like "20110217182000";...("20110217182000" - 2hours)
what is the problem na,
the current hours is like as "201102**17000000**",after subtracting this hour as should come with yesterday date...like the answer "201102**16220000**" in string format.......plz any one help me??????????
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you store the date in a Calendar object (named, say, `cal`), you can use

```
cal.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, -numberOfHours);
```

where `numberOfHours` is the amount you want to subtract.